# Best data structres to store a series of moves for a board game

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, game-development, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I have a board game called red swap blue.

The goal is to implement dfs and bfs in this game to solve it.

As a board game you know at every point of the game there are many choice to take one.
As in chess you have multi choices to decide which move to take.

In my game i can get the next move which could be a number of moves between 2 and 8.

The problem is that i do not know what a data structre I can use to save this states.
Like this:

```
                   Init stage
               /       |         \
              /        |          \
 possiblemove2    possiblemove2    possiblemov3
 |   |   |   |         |             |   |   |
Pm1 pm2 pm3 pm4       pm1           pm1 pm2 pm3 

...And so on...
```

Could not use binary tree cause it stores just two move for each stage.

Comment: I'm guessing that the algorithm you're referring to is usually called "minimax", rather than "dfs" or "bfs". Something like this: [Wikipedia: Minimax algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax#Minimax_algorithm_with_alternate_moves)

Comment: I suggest: 1) Represent the board state in some way, not worrying about trees or moves for now. 2) Write a function that is given a boardstate as input, and returns a list of possible moves as output. 3) Now you can write your tree-exploring function.

Comment: Note that trees don't have to be binary trees. You can build a tree where every node has a list of children.

Comment: Hi Stef, I am really thankfull for shareing your time with me. I have to implement dfs and bsf and then A*, I did 1 and two of what you suggested, but ehat do you mean with 3?

Comment: What?? A*? That's a path-finding algorithm, not a game-tree-exploring algorithm.

Comment: What do you mean with that?. I have to use these algorithm to find the solution. As a game it has many paths take you to find the solution. And every possible movement is like a point in the path and a sequence of movements represent a path that could make you win. My problem now is not the algoritm its self, but the data structure like tree or graph to store the possible movements and every sequence of movement is a path, and then i would write an algoritm to scan this data structure to find a good bath to win.

Comment: You typically don't store the tree, but make decisions *while* searching -- that is what minimax and alphabeta pruning have to offer.

Comment: The [left child right sibling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-child_right-sibling_binary_tree) binary tree is a great way to represent a graph that has a variable number of children at each node.